# Can't open file in ipython in windows

Tags: python, windows

I have just installed anaconda in windows and am using ipython. The  first thing I did was try to open a file so I can read it.

However I get the following errors.

```
f=open("C:\Users\user\Downloads\botnet-capture-20110810-neris.json")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e94e0c1093da> in <module>()
----> 1 f=open("C:\Users\user\Downloads\botnet-capture-20110810-neris.json")

IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\x08otnet-capture-20110810-neris.json
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you'd make sure the file **C:\Users\user\Downloads\botnet-capture-20110810-neris.json** exists.

Then the answer is

```
f=open(r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\botnet-capture-20110810-neris.json")
```

Note the **r** before the string indicating you're using raw string ignoring escapes in the filepath.

### Explanation

In Windows, the file system delimiter is '\' which leading an escape character in Python. The direct problem to your error is the '\b' character.

Instead of using raw string in Python, you could also escape the '\' by using '\\'. Now your file path looks like

```
f=open("C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\botnet-capture-20110810-neris.json")
```

Comment: That worked! I don't  need to do this in linux. Could you explain why windows needs this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `raw sting` like this because Windows using backslash in path:

```
f = open(r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\botnet-capture-20110810-neris.json")
```

[Here](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/) is a good document that explain why you need `raw sting` on Windows.

And by the way, I recommend use `with` like this:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\botnet-capture-20110810-neris.json") as f:
    # some code here
```

Answer (score 1):

\b is a character, use the forward slash syntax instead (as you do on Linux) :

f = open("C:/Users/user/Downloads/botnet-capture-20110810-neris.json")

Comment: I had no idea you could use a forward slash in  windows! Thank you.